# String request using Volley comes with unwanted HTML

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm trying to create a sample in my library for usages of Volley and the string request part does not seem to be working correctly. The code is straightforward and I cannot find a solution to why, when I use a URL to request a string online, it also includes the HTML tags along with it from the website it came from.

**How do I only pull the text, without the HTML coming too?**

```
// <<<<<<<<<<<STRING REQUEST>>>>>>>>
        // #1: A string from a URL.
        String url ="http://httpbin.org/html";
        final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stringView);

        // #2: Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Display the first 300 characters of the response string.
                        mTextView.setText(response.substring(0,300));
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
            }
        });
        // #3: Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
```

I display the string inside a `TextView`, and it should look like this:

> Herman Melville - Moby-Dick
>
> Availing himself of the mild, summer-cool weather that now reigned in
>   these latitudes, and in preparation for the peculiarly active pursuits
>   shortly to be anticipated, Perth, the begrimed, blistered old
>   blacksmith, had not removed his portable forge to the hold again,
>   after concluding his contributory work for Ahab's leg, but still
>   retained it on deck, fast lashed to ringbolts by the foremast; being
>   now almost incessantly invoked by the headsmen, and harpooneers, and
>   bowsmen to do some little job for them; altering, or repairing, or new
>   shaping their various weapons and boat furniture....

Instead it looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> <html>   <head>   </head>   <body>
      <h1>Herman Melville - Moby-Dick</h1>

      <div>
        <p>
          Availing himself of the mild, summer-cool weather that now reigned in these latitudes, and in preparation for the peculiarly active pursuits shortly to be anticipated, Perth, the begrimed, blistered old blacksmith, had not removed his portable forge to the hold again, after concluding his contributory work for Ahab's leg, but still retained it on deck, fast lashed to ringbolts by the foremast; being now almost incessantly invoked by the headsmen, and harpooneers, and bowsmen to do some little job for them; altering, or repairing, or new shaping their various weapons and boat furniture....
        </p>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The url returns html. What did you expect an http request to return, other than what the server returns? You either need to strip it out yourself, or parse it.

Comment: Then why does Volley call it a string request? It is not named properly. But I will find a way to parse it. I was just making sure I didn't leave something out by asking this question. I would have thought that Volley would be a complete solution, I guess not.

Comment: It's named correctly. HTML tags are strings.

Comment: Yes, technically, but it's actually code. Not what an Android user is accustomed to thinking of as a String.

Comment: HTML is not "code." It is a special string with formatting tags. Android "users" likely have no concept of "string" and Android developers (as any programmer) will understand that a "string" can contain HTML. This is nothing new.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Volley is not completely getting the StringRequest into what you might think of as a String format. So we have to parse the HTML ourselves. This can be done using [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/download), with very little code.

To add this into Android Studio open your module settings then select the "+" sign in the upper left, then select "Import .JAR/.AAR Package", then choose your jar download from your file system.

Be sure to then add `compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'` to your build.gradle file.

Modified code is below:

```
// <<<<<<<<<<<STRING REQUEST>>>>>>>>
        // #1: A string from a URL.
        String url ="http://httpbin.org/html";
        final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stringView);

        // #2: Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Use Jsoup to parse HTML
                        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(response);
                        String parsedText = doc.body().text();
                        // Display the first 300 characters of the response string.
                        mTextView.setText(parsedText.substring(0,300));
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
            }
        });
```